# Multiple different Admob banner ads in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, admob, ads

I have a `CollectionView` that has an infinite scroll and I'm trying to make it so that every 9th cell there's an Admob banner ad instead of the regular content.

I want to make sure that every ad is different from the previous one. However, as far as I understand that means that every new ad needs to have a new `adUnitID` which I have to create manually through the Admob website.

Is it possible to display a **different** ad every 9th cell?

That's the code I currently have. It works but it displays the same ad over and over again:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       if (indexPath.item % 9 == 0) {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: adCellId, for: indexPath) as! AdCell

           let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: adViewHeight))
           let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)

           bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
           bannerView.delegate = self
           bannerView.rootViewController = self
           bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           let request = GADRequest()
           bannerView.load(request)

           cell.contentView.addSubview(bannerView)

           return cell

        } else {
           // ...
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrAdUnitID = [String array of all Ad Unit ID]
var currentIndexForAdd = 0
var currentIndexForNormalRow = 0


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       if (indexPath.item % 9 == 0) {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: adCellId, for: indexPath) as! AdCell

           let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: adViewHeight))
           let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)

           bannerView.adUnitID = arrAdUnitID[currentIndexForAdd]
           currentIndexForAdd += 1
           bannerView.delegate = self
           bannerView.rootViewController = self
           bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           let request = GADRequest()
           bannerView.load(request)

           cell.contentView.addSubview(bannerView)

           return cell

        } else {
           cell.title.text = arrDataToShow[currentIndexForNormalRow] // It can be any thing like image or text which you want to show
           currentIndexForNormalRow += 1 
        }
}
```